# Printing multiplication tables as per form input - Not printing result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate and print the result of multiplication tables.

The form accepts the Number and the start and end range for multiplication.

The result should print in the format "12 x 1 = 12" and so on

Everything is working except the last line to print the result of the calculation in the 'content' div.

The result just flashes for a second. No errors

HTML

```
<form name="multiply">
    <p>Enter the number: <input type="number" id="myNum"></p>
    <p>From: <input type="number" id="sValue"> To: <input type="number" id="eValue"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Calculate" onclick="timesTable()">
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Javascript

```
        function timesTable() {
        Num = document.getElementById("myNum").value;
        startValue = document.getElementById("sValue").value;
        endValue = document.getElementById("eValue").value;
        var result = [];

        for (var i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {

            result[i] = Num * i;

            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = Num + " x " + i + " = " + result[i] + "<br>";
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to insert into DOM after for loop.

```js
function timesTable() {
  total="";
        Num = document.getElementById("myNum").value;
        startValue = document.getElementById("sValue").value;
        endValue = document.getElementById("eValue").value;
        var result = [];

        for (var i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {

            result[i] = Num * i;

             total=total+" "+ Num + " x " + i + " = " + result[i] + "<br>";
        }
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=total;
        }
```

```html
<form name="multiply" onsubmit="return false;">
    <p>Enter the number: <input type="number" id="myNum"></p>
    <p>From: <input type="number" id="sValue"> To: <input type="number" id="eValue"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Calculate" onclick="timesTable()">
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Its working but when i click the button, i see the output flash for a second and then empty again.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: in your case or my case ?

Comment: Both yours and Geekys solutions are giving the same problem. The code is working but result doesn't remain on screen.

Comment: oh that's because when you click on submit button . the form is submitted and you will see blank page . to prevent this you can use inline attribute of `onsubmit="return false;`  i have edited :)

Comment: sorry i understood your doubt lately . because it was working here not in localhost

Answer (score 1):

It is typical closure problem. It is displaying the last entered value.

change your code to the following

```js
function timesTable() {
  Num = document.getElementById("myNum").value;
  startValue = document.getElementById("sValue").value;
  endValue = document.getElementById("eValue").value;
  var result = [];
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var res=[];
  for (var i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {

    result[i] = Num * i;
    res.push( (function(i) {

      return Num + " x " + i + " = " + result[i] + "<br>"
    })(i));

  }
  content.innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<form name="multiply">
  <p>Enter the number:
    <input type="number" id="myNum">
  </p>
  <p>From:
    <input type="number" id="sValue">To:
    <input type="number" id="eValue">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="Calculate" onclick="timesTable()">
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Hope this helps